# Install deleted Keynote app in MAC

Tags: macos, mac, install, keynote

I uninstalled Keynote app from Applications, since I am unable to update it because of the error

**[image: Update Unavailable with This Apple ID]**

I empty trash and try to reinstall it again. I am getting the same error. And its still showing **UPDATE** option, not **GET** option.

I am getting this problem with this version of mac(v10.12.5), previous versions I updated successfully with my appleid.

Any help on this..

Comment: Quick check - sign out of the Store, try to get the app again, check what ID it presents in the sign-in dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am successful in reinstalling Keynote by following these steps,

1. Move Keynote app from Applications to Trash.
2. Empty trash.

   - its still shows **UPDATE** option, not **GET** option for Keynote in Appstore.
3. Power **OFF** and **ON** the MAC.
4. Appstore shows **GET** option for Keynote now.

It works fine even for Numbers, Pages. Please edit this post, if any feasible solution available.